# increase MAX_TYPES in Metric-FF

Tags: logic, artificial-intelligence, pddl

I use the planner Metric-FF. After the specification of the problem and domain files I get the error "too many (inferred) types! increase MAX_TYPES (currently 50)". I have many types specified (and might need even more).

Do you know how to increase the number of allowed types?

Answer (score 0):

Edit ff.h and change the line:
`#define MAX_TYPES 50`
to whatever value you see fit.

clean and recompile

```
make clean
make
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!